# Workflow time triggers not removed from queue when record no longer matches criteria

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I have a checkbox on an object set to true by default. I have a workflow rule with 2 time triggers (set to 2 date fields which I am populating using formula fields) to update the same checkbox to false. In the rule criteria, I have specified the condition that the checkbox must be true. But after the earlier time trigger fires and the checkbox is made false, the other time trigger is not removed from the queue. I think this is because I did not check the Re-evaluate Workflow Rules on the field update. If I check that, will the records be removed from the queue?

Comment: Yes you have to check that check box